# How to HTML select in jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I want to select several options with the help of jquery. and take the value of the selected options and write it in the paragraph. My problem is that it only takes the first option and does not take the next selected option and only returns the value obtained first. I have to write it in

until there are no other options. and I need to delete the selected options

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 26;
  var wrapper = $(".container1");
  var add_button = $(".add_form_field");
  var selectopion = $("#id_100 option:selected").val();
  var x = 1;
  $(add_button).click(function(e) {
    $("#id_100 option:selected").remove();
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) {
      var numbers = x++;
      //add input box
      $(wrapper).append('<div><p>ID: ' + selectopion + ' student</p></div>');
    } else {
      alert('The maximum number of students has been added');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<label for="day">Students</label>
<select name="students_info" class="form-control" id="id_100">
  <option value="6">6 || student</option>
  <option value="5">5 || student</option>
  <option value="4">4 || student</option>
  <option value="3">3 || student</option>
  <option value="2">2 || student</option>
  <option value="1">1 || student</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="button" id="submit_button" 
  class="btn btn-success add_form_field" value="Add">
<div class="container1 form-group"></div>
```

Comment: I don't understand "add demand +".

Comment: Off topic: `for="day"` should be `for="id_100"`

Comment: Objective: Write it in paragraphs until the html selection is complete

Comment: Off topic 2: `$(add_button).click(function (e) {` should be `add_button.click(function (e) {` and `$(wrapper).append` to `wrapper.append`

Comment: Try the html code

Comment: The `select` is not marked as `multiple`, so you can only select one item at a time. If you want to select more than one at a time, add a `multiple` attribute to the HTML and use `$('#id_100').val()` to get a list of selected items.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a clearer description. Comments are for asking for clarification, the response should be to update the question with that clarification.

Comment: The value of `selectopion` is the value that was selected when document.ready happened.  It looks like that declaration should be inside the click handler instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you only retrieve the `val()` of the select when the page loads. You need to get that value when the event occurs, so that it matches what has been selected in the DOM when the user clicks the button.

In addition you need to move the `remove()` call to *after* you append the `div`, otherwise the selected `option` is removed before it's been read.

Also note that in several instances you're wrapping jQuery objects in another jQuery object. Select your elements once and refer to them as necessary within the event handlers.

Finally, you can look use the `length` property to determine how many elements you've appended to the DOM instead of the global `x` variable.

> This is great, but it will continue to write null when the options run out

This is easily fixed by ensuring that the select had a value.

Try this working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 26;
  var $wrapper = $(".container1");
  var $add_button = $(".add_form_field");
  var $select = $("#id_100");
  
  $add_button.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    
    let selectValue = $select.val();    
    if (!selectValue)
      return;
    
    if ($wrapper.children('div').length < max_fields) {
      $wrapper.append(`<div><p>ID: ${selectValue} student</p></div>`);
      $select.find('option:selected').remove();
    } else {
      alert('The maximum number of students has been added');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<label for="day">Students</label>
<select name="students_info" class="form-control" id="id_100">
  <option value="6">6 || student</option>
  <option value="5">5 || student</option>
  <option value="4">4 || student</option>
  <option value="3">3 || student</option>
  <option value="2">2 || student</option>
  <option value="1">1 || student</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="button" id="submit_button" class="btn btn-success add_form_field" value="Add">
<div class="container1 form-group"></div>
```

Comment: This is great, but it will continue to write null when the options run out

Comment: I updated the answer to show you how to add that restriction